# Prime-run command not found

Tags: nvidia

Command prime-run outputs `prime-run: command not found`.
I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 and nvidia-driver-470

Comment: What is prime-run? Also on my system the same... Looks like you have to add a repository

Comment: I suppose you mean `optirun` from [bumblebee package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Foptirun)...

Answer (score 13):

I have the same nvidia driver version and for some reason `prime-run` command does not exist.

I just solved it by doing the following:

1. Copy contents of the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/abenson/a5264836c4e6bf22c8c8415bb616204a)

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   export __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
   export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
   export __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
   export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
   exec "$@"
   ```
2. Create a file `~/bin/prime-run` ("~" means your home directory)
3. Paste the contents there.
4. Run `chmod +x "~/bin/prime-run"` to make it executable.

You might want to re-open your terminal or restart your session so your terminal could recognize your `~/bin` folder and be able to run `prime-run` command, that is, if the folder is not already there.

Comment: Nice workaround. prime-run was part of the proprietary nvidia drivers in the past. I assume that the command has been deprecated, for whatever reason and now removed.

Comment: I installed nvidia 510.60.02 with runfile and I don't have /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json. Is the file the same as /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json?

Comment: Thanks this worked with 535.54.03

Comment: @Gorgo probably, but why don't you install NVidia drivers from Ubuntu packages? That way you can be sure you can cleanly remove or upgrade them without having to manually clean up the file mess the non-ubuntu installer creates